"Client Invalid Error" Discord API for OAuth2
I was coding a basic program in JavaScript using axios and express to learn more about how OAuth2 worked when my client All of the sudden gave an error.
Error: 400 (Bad Request)
This is the part of the code it errors on:
//^^^^^^^^^^
// defining web server

const formData = new url.URLSearchParams({
    client_id: webid,
    client_secret: websecret,
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    code: code.toString(),
    redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
});

const oauthInfo = await axios.post('https://discord.com/api/v10/oauth2/token',
    formData, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        }
});

// below is starting everything           

Full code: https://pastebin.com/FbHVkKRi

Hello there! What error did you get? Please review the guidelines for how to ask a good question at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

formData must be type of String, not an Object.
const oauthInfo = await axios({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  data: new URLSearchParams({
    client_id: webid,
    client_secret: websecret,
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    code: code,
    redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
    scope: 'identify guilds',
  }).toString();
});


Still giving the same error.

Please check if your redirect url is set on the discord developer portal. Check for scopes in the OAuth2 url, if any - add a field with scope: 'your scopes' in the FormData
